# keep real values using awk format convertor

Tags: awk, integer, format

I recently asked the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046438/converting-sparse-matrix-to-arff-using-awk) regarding format conversion using awk that was answered by Ed Morton. However, I need assistance making an adjustment in this awk code.
When creating the file, instead of keeping the actual integer values (which contain decimals) the awk script seems to round down to the nearest whole number. Is there a way to modify this script to keep the actual values in the dataset.

So for instance:

```
church place 3.43
church institution 6.92
man place 86.39
man food 63.39
woman book 37.04
```

becomes

```
@relation 'filename'
@attribute "place" string
@attribute "institution" string
@attribute "food" string
@attribute "book" string


@data
3,6,0,0,church
86,0,63,0,man
0,0,0,37,woman
```

instead of

```
@relation 'filename'
@attribute "place" string
@attribute "institution" string
@attribute "food" string
@attribute "book" string


@data
3.43,6.92,0,0,church
86.39,0,63.39,0,man
0,0,0,37.04,woman
```

Is there a way that the awk from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046438/converting-sparse-matrix-to-arff-using-awk) can be altered to include the real value instead of just rounding to the nearest whole integer?

Comment: Why not just update your original post?  This is solved by trimming of the decimals in the code posted by Ed

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Jotne. I have been looking at how the code is written and have also read over the basic fundamentals of the print function in awk (as found [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_7.html)). I understand that solving this problem is related to the printf "%d", but if you can point me a bit more in the direction towards how to "untrim" the decimals in the code, it would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Run this `awk -F. '{print $1}' file` before Eds code.  It will strip of decimals.

Comment: Thank you for your response Jotne, but I want to KEEP the decimals, not strip them away.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood :) It was the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use %g or %s instead of %d when printing the numeric values, e.g.:

```
printf "%g,", score[row,attr]
```

or

```
printf "%s,", score[row,attr]+0
```

Note you need to add zero when using %s so null strings get converted to number zero.

Comment: Thank you Ed, I tried both options, and the result was the same as %d (meaning that it is still printing whole integers.) I copied and pasted each of your solutions into the original code to try and neither seemed to produce the decimals. I do not know what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Me neither. Update your question to show your modified code, the input file, and the output you get with both the %g and %s variations.

Comment: I went through it carefully again and I found that the error was my own. A missing comma, in fact. Both of Ed's proposed solutions to modify the printf variable solve the above problem.