# How to convert sparse matrix data into WEKA's arff file format?

Tags: awk, converters, weka, arff

I have a sparse matrix .txt file, containing many numbers, but mostly 0's. Here is a sample from this .txt file:

> 0 0   0.271178    0   0   0   0.538776    0   -0.631228   0   0   -0.501485   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.438643    0   0   0   0   0   0.287754    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -0.498918   0   0   0   0   0   0.475561    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.370479    0   -0.300765   0   -1.10987    0   0   0.163637    0   0   0   0   0   0   0.304006    0   0.181697    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -0.261758   0   0   0   0.153415    0.17412 0   -0.129725   0   0.17598 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.56053 0   0   -0.211302   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.213277    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0698458   0   0   0   0.661972    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.376654    0   0   -0.604655   0   0   0   0   0   0.301025    0   0   -0.431324   0   0   -0.139445   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.404718    0.610013    -0.286108   0   0.46045 0   0   0   0   0   0   -0.193543   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.315063    0   0   -0.285598   0   0   0.206607    0

What I need to do is to be able to go through this file and convert the data into [WEKA's](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)
recognizable file format, .arff, so I can run data-mining algorithms on the data set. Does anyone know how to do this? I found a few similar questions on StackOverflow that is similar to my problem, however, they are using a script in the AWK language, and I have never used .awk programs before, so I could not get those programs to run correctly.
Here are the links to those posts:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046438/converting-sparse-matrix-to-arff-using-awk) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234232/too-many-attributes-for-arff-format-in-weka)

Comment: What should the output file look like?

Answer (score 1):

Had a look at [the ARFF file format](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29) and the questions you linked.

You can embed awk programs inside a shell script pretty easily, so you can do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$1
awk '
    BEGIN {print "@RELATION something\n"} 
    {
        data = sep = ""
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i != 0) {
                printf "@ATTRIBUTE a_%d NUMERIC\n", i
                data = data sep $i
                sep = ","
            }
        print ""
        print "@DATA"
        print data
    }
' "$file"
```

Call the script with: `bash script.sh data_file` and see

```
@RELATION something

@ATTRIBUTE a_3 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_7 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_9 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_12 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_33 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_39 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_52 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_58 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_70 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_72 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_74 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_77 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_84 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_86 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_124 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_128 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_129 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_131 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_133 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_141 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_144 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_152 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_185 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_189 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_207 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_210 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_216 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_219 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_222 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_238 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_239 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_240 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_242 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_249 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_257 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_260 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE a_263 NUMERIC

@DATA
0.271178,0.538776,-0.631228,-0.501485,0.438643,0.287754,-0.498918,0.475561,0.370479,-0.300765,-1.10987,0.163637,0.304006,0.181697,-0.261758,0.153415,0.17412,-0.129725,0.17598,0.56053,-0.211302,0.213277,0.0698458,0.661972,0.376654,-0.604655,0.301025,-0.431324,-0.139445,0.404718,0.610013,-0.286108,0.46045,-0.193543,0.315063,-0.285598,0.206607
```

But you'll have to let us know if that's what you want to output.

Comment: +1 for going the extra 26 miles to investigate the problem! I was just going to tell the OP to abbreviate their input and post the expected output!

Answer (score 0):

Great script [Glenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman), but it is missing the index and putting it in the attribute name. Something like:

```
@attribute a_0 numeric
@attribute a_1 numeric
@attribute a_2 numeric
@attribute a_3 numeric
...

@data
{3 0.271178,...}
```

This is the required sparse ARFF format for avoiding missing the attribute position information. My recommendation is going for a dense format (just CSV) and using the WEKA filter `NonSparseToSparse`.